# Integrate python with react

Tags: python, react-native, chatbot

I have build an simple chatbot in python, but the framework for the UI in python is not what I want to use to build a UI. I want to use react to make the UI for better and more professional look to the chatbot.
So my question is can I do that, if yes, then how? And I would like to test it on an mobile app as well, how do you guys suggest I go forward with that?

I appreciate every respond.

Comment: Start with: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework like Django and the Django-rest-framework for the backend, and use React for the frontend. You could also use React-native to build mobile apps out of it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it